# How do I make a true ghost sign?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

btw, "Impossible" is not an answer. This just shows you aren't thinking outside the box.
With that said, here's the question:

---

So, what I want to do is make a "ghost" or "floating" sign. Something that looks like this:

[image: A sign on a barrier block (hidden)]

However, it's not as easy as that, since I've cheated and went ahead and used a Barrier Block:

[image: A sign on a barrier block (shown)]

What I want to do however, is make a true "ghost" or "floating" sign; one that does not need to rest on any sort of block as you cannot walk through that (unless it's water*, lava* or other signs).

It's possible to do so using [WorldEdit](https://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/worldedit) by selecting a region and then doing `//set wall_sign`. However, this sign is rather blank.

*You can't rest a sign against any liquids anyway.

[image: I used WorldEdit... Only that the sign is blank.]

I remembered there was a trick that you could use to delete/add/modify blocks without triggering a block update (which is what causes a sign to break when it has no resting block). Any ideas?

You're free to use any server plugin (existing or a pointer in coding a new one) or a vanilla method. Just pop `minecraft:` to the front of your command... So `/tp` is now `/minecraft:tp`.

---

Bonus points if you can figure out a way that allows multiple signs side-by-side.

Comment: In WorldEdit you should be able to set signs with text: `//set wall_sign|Line1_with_spaces|Line2|Line3` (Spaces are not allowed and need to be replaced with underscores.)  ..I'm not on the right computer to test it though.

Comment: @dly Just to confirm: It's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a so-called "invalid state", because the sign is not meant to be there in a normal situation. So you always have to abuse a bug or external editor to get it there and then be careful to not change anything on any of the six adjacent blocks ever again.

**With commands**, you can just use `/setblock`, because it doesn't update the block ([MC-31100](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-31100)). But you have to specify everything about the sign. The one in your example can be set like this:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ oak_wall_sign[facing=north]{Text1:"{\"text\":\"\"}",Text2:"{\"text\":\"This is a\"}",Text3:"{\"text\":\"floating sign\"}",Text4:"{\"text\":\"\"}"}
```

You  have to replace the `north` with `south`, `east` or `west` for the other directions.

**Without commands**, you'll likely have to use stack overflows for update suppression, since most other bugs that do it are fixed. For that, you can for example use a machine like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mzfLHNeqjuY).

Answer (score -3):

If you're on 1.13, you could use the debug stick to set the sign to 'wall'

Comment: Nice try, but how would I place it, to begin with? Also, if I was to place a block (because it's one above the ground), place a ground sign, debug stick it and destroyed that block... It'll still break due to block update.

Comment: this is not yet possible, sure there are snapshots, but let's say the map is for 1.12, how will he downgrade?

Comment: @Diriector_Doc I don't. I just upgrade.